# display product price in google search result

Tags: seo, google-search

While I search for the magento module in google, I noticed the price is displayed in google search. Can we display the price of the product in google search by using any tag or any other way. Someone tell me what method is used in this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento makes use of hProduct microformat, and that is read by google.

But obviously you don't need to use Magento in order to get google index your product prices. Take a look at google microformat description page:

- [Rich snippets - Products](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146750)

Be aware though that it might take a while for google to index microformat correctly. Best thing to do if you want to accelerate the process is to use this microformat in multiple locations around the website. Still though in some of my websites it took over a month after initial indexing till I could actually see my product prices on google.

Comment: It can take months, and in some cases it can actually take much longer. In other cases it doesn't seem to happen at all. I operate sites that have hundreds of products. We implemented hProduct microformat about a year ago. Some of the products will show all parts of the microformat, some will show certain parts of the microformat, and others none at all. I really have no idea what the criteria is.